# live search with jquery, ajax, json, php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am looking for a live search solution or jquery autocomplete using ajax to take data from a file (later from db)

Let's say i have this php file with data:

```
[ 
 {ID: "1", "Name": "User 1"}, 
 {ID: "2", "Name": "User 2"},  
 {ID: "3", "Name": "User 3"}, 
 {ID: "4", "Name": "User 4"}
]
```

---

I found on the web this code it works but it scanns only wikipedia, how can i make is to scann my php file? http://jsfiddle.net/TzQJP/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <title>Comperio Super Simple Instant Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Search Wikipedia!</h1>
    <br />
    <input id="searchterm" />
    <button id="search">search</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
      $("#searchterm").keyup(function(e){
        var q = $("#searchterm").val();
        $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?",
        {
          srsearch: q,
          action: "query",
          list: "search",
          format: "json"
        },
        function(data) {
          $("#results").empty();
          $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
          $.each(data.query.search, function(i,item){
            $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;text-align:right">
      <a href="http://blog.comperiosearch.com/author/fmcdowall/">Fergus McDowall</a> 2012<br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By change `"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?"` path to your PHP file path you can accomplish it. Make sure that your JSON result it correctly formatted and a valid one.

*Don't just take code snippets from the internet and use it. At least get an idea what it does. It may help you to extend the code as you want.*

Comment: i did that, and nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Why not use: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

example from the same website:

```
$(function() {
 var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C"
 ];
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags //OR path to your PHP script
 });
});
```

and you can have path to your PHP script instead of availableTags in source that returns

```
echo json_encode($array_of_items);
```

If you still want to use the code you provided, make sure you do `echo json_encode($array);` on your PHP script since response ajax is expecting should be type of `json`

Comment: I really cant get it to work. I never worked before with ajax or live search.

Comment: its pretty easy just read up API documentation, all you gotta do is download the files include it on your <head></head> and use the example i gave you above but change #tags into your input id.

Comment: Well, my only problem is with the connection between my search.php script and the javascript code... I dont understand the connection :)

Comment: This won't work with JSON data or multidimensional arrays. You can convert some of the JSON to a single dimensional array, but if you need more than one piece of data to be associated with a result (such as for books for example - a title, author, year and maybe a page id to link to a page for the book), jQuery's autocomplete will not not work without some serious custom coding.